# Term for someone's face which gives good mood to you

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for someone's face which gives you good mood when you see it? It's like "uplifting" but I think this fits for the action like performance.

Comment: Probably not what you’re looking for, but the first thing that popped into my head when I saw your question title was, ‘A sight for sore eyes’. But, it’s really more along the lines of what a man might say when spotting a beautiful woman, though I have heard it used to describe scenery and wholesome stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Radiant" would have my vote. It is strongly evocative of sunlight, and who doesn't instinctively smile in the sun?

Comment: My one true ex loves grey skies.

Comment: Well, aside from oddballs like them ;)